# animation of TextView's text size

Tags: android, animation, text, size, textview

I want to be able to do a text animation and change the size of the text in a TextView. I read that there are property animations in android but if someone knows a simple code that can do this for me or an example somewhere I will deeply appreciate it. Thank u in advance!

Comment: Related [Animation of android TextView's text size and not the entire TextView](//stackoverflow.com/a/30324368)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

scale.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <scale
          android:fromXScale="1.0"
          android:fromYScale="1.0"
          android:toXScale="2.0"
          android:toYScale="2.0"
          android:duration="3000"></scale>
</set>
```

A function into an Activity:

```
private void RunAnimation() 
{
    Animation a = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.scale);
    a.reset();
    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.firstTextView);
    tv.clearAnimation();
    tv.startAnimation(a);
}
```

extracted and modified from [here](http://android10.org/index.php/articlesgraphicsaudiovideo/272-more-animation-in-android-part-2)

Comment: Thank u this helped me a lot. But I was also wandering could it be done with a property animation on the text, and not the whole text view?

Comment: `scale.xml` goes under **/res/anim/**

Answer (score 6):

```
Animation animation=new TranslateAnimation(0,480,0,0); 
animation.setDuration(5000);
animation.setRepeatMode(Animation.RESTART);
animation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
text.startAnimation(animation);
// applying animation to textview object..
```

If you are using button event to show animation then put the code inside onClick() otherwise use override method onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) to start animation

Answer (score 6):

Use ValueAnimator class in the android

```
final float startSize = o; // Size in pixels
    final float endSize = 30;
    final int animationDuration = 1000; // Animation duration in ms

    ValueAnimator animator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(startSize, endSize);
    animator.setDuration(animationDuration);

    animator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
            float animatedValue = (float) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue();
            tv.setTextSize(animatedValue);
        }
    });

    animator.start();
```

refer this link [ValueAnimator](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ValueAnimator.html)

Another solution  is that apply scale animation on Textview or its parent layout

```
ScaleAnimation scaleAnimation = new ScaleAnimation(0.7f, 1.1f, 0.7f, 1.1f, ScaleAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f,
                   ScaleAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
scaleAnimation.setDuration(600);
viewZoom.startAnimation(scaleAnimation);
```

Comment: Copied code from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30324368/2025923)

Comment: Works not smoothly even on OnePlus3T (