# Animation of a TextView's text size and not the entire TextView

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

Is there a way to animate only the TextView's text size without scaling the entire TextView's layout?

[image]

Am trying to achieve a similar effect, Note the text re-sizes to a single line while its size becomes smaller.

Comment: use ObjectAnimator/ValueAnimator

Comment: @pskink some More details will be helpfull

Comment: Have you tried setting a fixed minimum height of the TextView? `textView.setMinHeight()`.

Comment: @Kerry Sorry, how does that help with the animation?

Comment: Misunderstood your questions, I thought you didn't want the sisze of the text box to change as the font size changed.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

This could be achieved with a `ValueAnimator` and from the top of my head I think it should look something like this:

```
final TextView tv = new TextView(getApplicationContext());

final float startSize = 42; // Size in pixels
final float endSize = 12;
long animationDuration = 600; // Animation duration in ms

ValueAnimator animator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(startSize, endSize);
animator.setDuration(animationDuration);

animator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
        float animatedValue = (float) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue();
        tv.setTextSize(animatedValue);
    }
});

animator.start();
```

Answer (score 9):

As a follow up on @korrekorre answer: The documentation suggests to use the simpler [ObjectAnimator API](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html#object-animator)

```
final TextView tv = new TextView(getApplicationContext());

final float endSize = 12;
final int animationDuration = 600; // Animation duration in ms

ValueAnimator animator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(tv, "textSize", endSize);
animator.setDuration(animationDuration);

animator.start();
```

There is just one caveat: The property you pass to the constructor (`"textSize"` in this case) **must** have a public setter method for this to work.

You can also pass a `startSize` to the constructor, if you don't then the interpolator will use the current size as starting point

Comment: More efficient solution!

Comment: Another thing to note: `TextView.getTextSize()` returns the size in `dp`, so leaving it to the default value may result in an unwanted effect. So setting the `startSize` manually to "sp" via `tv.textSize / resources.displayMetrics.density` may be desirable.

Comment: @Beko instead of `resources.displayMetrics.density`  use `resources.displayMetrics.scaledDensity` for text size.

Answer (score 1):

With Kotlin, create an extension function like this:

```
fun TextView.sizeScaleAnimation(endSize: Float, durationInMilliSec: Long) {
    val animator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(this, "textSize", endSize)
    animator.duration = durationInMilliSec
    animator.start()
}
```

Use it like this:

```
 val endSize = resources.getDimension(R.dimen.my_new_text_size)
 myTextView.sizeScaleAnimation(endSize, 200L)
```