# How to increase TextView size and get width of it in for loop, Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, textview

When button click a for loop starts and in for loop I am increasing text size and log the width of TextView. but it is not increasing size and always getting the same width(check the log added below). I added my full code. How to fix this?

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
        android:text="00:00" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:onClick="ocBtnIncrease"
        android:text="Increase" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.test;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    TextView tv;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        tv = findViewById(R.id.tv);
    }

    public void ocBtnIncrease(View view) {
        for (int i = 1; i < 500; i++) {
            tv.setTextSize(i);
            Log.i(TAG, "i: " + i);
            Log.i(TAG, "WIDTH: " + tv.getWidth());
            SystemClock.sleep(500);
        }
    }
}
```

**Log**

```
I/MainActivity: i: 1
I/MainActivity: WIDTH: 71
I/MainActivity: i: 2
I/MainActivity: WIDTH: 71
I/MainActivity: i: 3
I/MainActivity: WIDTH: 71
I/MainActivity: i: 4
.
.
```

Answer (score 0):

Use setTextSize() like this:

```
tv.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 18f);
```

Original answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9494097/6751083)

Comment: I think **ValueAnimator** could help: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30324368/6751083)

Comment: I want to use this mechanism in some other task. not animations.